# Can a stolen sefer Torah be used?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, gezel-stealing

If a shul buys a sefer Torah that turns out to be stolen, what happens?
May they continue using it? Are they *yotzei* on the  readings they've performed in the past?

Comment: Generally one shouldn't say blessings on stolen items בצע ברך נאץ יהוה

Comment: blessings arent meakev the Torah reading @DoubleAA

Comment: it would depend if the mitzvah of krias haTorah has a din of shmia or a din of kria

Comment: @sam על שלא ברכו תחילה... Plus we may be talking about a Deorayta

Comment: I beileve Rav Moshe brought a proof from the shul of Alexandria that Krias haTorah has a din of shmia forgot where

Comment: http://www.zomet.org.il/?CategoryID=259&ArticleID=241#_Toc175379329

Comment: @GershonGold Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rav Uri Dasberg](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%93%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%92) says that l'Chatchila one can not make a Bracha on a stolen object. Therefore no Bracha may be said over a stolen Torah. He brings in the name of [Sh"ut Bais Yitzchak Yore Deah 2:109](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=619&pgnum=486) that there may be room to even allow one to make a Bracha on a stolen Torah, however even the Sh"ut Bais Yitzchak says that one should L'chatchila not make a Bracha on a stolen Torah.

> לכתחילה קריאת התורה כוללת בתוכה גם כן ברכת התורה. לגבי ברכה על חפץ
>   גזול קובע התלמוד (ב"ק צד, א סנהדרין ו, ב) את הפסוק (תהילים י, ג) "בוצע
>   ברך נאץ ה"', ואין זה מברך אלא מנאץ. על כן אף אם יוצא אדם בקריאה בספר
>   גזול אין הוא רשאי לברך עליה הלכה דומה נפסקה בשולחן ערוך (או"ח תרצא,
>   יא) שאע"פ שאדם יוצא ידי חובתו בקריאה במגילה גזולה, אין הוא רשאי לברך
>   עליה, כשם שעל לולב גזול אין לברך (שו"ע או"ה תרמט, א).‏
>
> בשו"ת בית יצחק[16] יו"ד ח"ב סי' קט כתב שיש מקום לחלק בין קריאת המגילה
>   לקריאת התורה, שבעוד שבקריאת התורה הברכה היא על התורה ולא על מצות
>   הקריאה ("אשר בחר בנו מכל העמים ונתן לנו את תורתו . . . נותן התורה")
>   הרי במגילה הברכה ה"א על מצות הקריאה ("אשר קדשנו במצוותיו וצוונו על
>   מקרא מגילה"). כשבא אדם לקיים מצוה בחפץ גזול ומברך על קיום המצוה - אין
>   זה מברך אלא מנאץ, אולם כשאין הברכה על קיום המצוה - אפשר שעל כך לא נקבע
>   שזה ניאוץ. אעפ"כ הוא פוסק שאין לברך לכתחילה.‏

B'dieved the Yesodei Yeshurun says that one does fulfill their obligation with a stolen Torah, however Sefer Chasidim seemingly disagrees.

> בדיעבד לגבי קריאת המגילה נפסק בשו"ע (או"ח תרצא, יא) שאם קרא במגילה גזולה יצא. הנימוק ההלכתי לכך הוא שכיון שיוצאים בקריאת המגילה שהיא
>   תוצאה של קול, הרי קול אינו נגזל, ועל כן יוצאים ידי חובה במגילה גזולה.
>   בספר יסודי ישורון[20] מסכם שורה של בעלי תשובות המשווים דין קריאת התורה
>   לדין מקרא מגילה, ופוסקים שבדיעבד הקורא בתורה גזולה יצא ידי חובתו. אמנם
>   עי' בספר חסידים (מהדו' ה"ר מרגליות הוצאת מוסד הרב קוק תשיז) סי' תשעב,
>   שמי שחטף סדור תפלה מחברו חייב להתפלל שנית, כי התפלה הראשונה לא עלתה
>   לו. אבל אפשר שזה רק ממידת חסידות.‏
>
> לעניננו פירושו של דבר שהנזילות מצד רוכש הגזילה אינה חסומה לחלוטין.
>   אמנם המסקנות מהנ"ל הן שחובה על רוכש ספר תורה לבחון היטב מה מקור הספר,
>   שמא הוא גזול. אולם הידיעה שבדיעבד מי שקרא בספר-תורה גזול יצא ידי חובתו
>   עלולה להביא לחוסר העמקה בבדיקות המוקדמות, אם בכלל הן תעשינה.‏

[Zomet.Org.Il](http://www.zomet.org.il/?CategoryID=259&ArticleID=241#_Toc175379329)

Comment: Do any of these sources differentiate between before one knows it is stolen, and after, which the op asked about separately?

Comment: @mevaqesh I asked two things -- if they may continue using it -- they shouldn't, and they [probably] can't make the brachot even if they do; if their previous usage counts -- b'dieved yes.